# How is w1_to_w2.count and w2_to_w1.count working

Tags: c++, unordered-map

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> findAndReplacePattern(vector<string>& words, string p) {
        vector<string> ans;
        for(auto &w:words){
            if(match(w,p))
                ans.push_back(w);
        }
        return ans;
    }
    bool match(string &w1,string &w2){
        unordered_map<char,char>w1_to_w2,w2_to_w1;
        for( i=0;i<w1.size();i++)
            if( (w1_to_w2.count(w1[i]) && w1_to_w2[w1[i]] != w2[i]) || 
                (w2_to_w1.count(w2[i]) && w2_to_w1[w2[i]] != w1[i]) ) 
                return false; 
            else
                w1_to_w2[w1[i]] = w2[i],
                w2_to_w1[w2[i]] = w1[i];
    
        return true;
    }
};
```

Input:
words = ["abc","deq","mee","aqq","dkd","ccc"]
pattern = "abb"

Output:
["mee","aqq"]

Explanation:
"mee" matches the pattern because there is a permutation `{a -> m, b -> e, ...}`. "ccc" does not match the pattern because `{a -> c, b -> c, ...}` is not a permutation, since `a` and `b` map to the same letter.

How is this working, especially `count`? Please explain step by step.

Comment: You can find the info you're looking for here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count

Comment: Are you asking what all these lines of code do, or specifically what `std::unordered_map::count()` does?

Answer (score 0):

`findAndReplacePattern(words, p)` just calls `match(`*word*`, p)` for each *word* in `words` - if they match then *word* is appended to `ans`, which is later returned.

In `match(w1, w2)`, `w1_to_w2` and `w2_to_w1` are initially empty, and `i` counts its way along both strings (which are assumed to be of the same length - often a dangerous assumption that can lead to programs that crash).

On the first iteration when `i` is 0, the `.count(...)` calls return 0 because there's nothing in the unordered_maps, so the function doesn't return.  Instead if evaluates the `else` clause, which records that:

- the first letter in `w1` - `w1[0]` - corresponds to the first letter in `w2`, by doing the assignment `w1_to_w2[w1[i]] = w2[i]`, and
- the first letter in `w2` - `w2[0]` - corresponds to the first letter in `w1`, by doing the assignment `w2_to_w1[w2[i]] = w1[i]`.

As it makes its way along the rest of the letters in the words...

```
w1_to_w2.count(w1[i]) && w1_to_w2[w1[i]] != w2[i]
```

...is saying that if we've already seen the same letter as `w1[i]` before in `w1` and the letter in `w2` it corresponded to before (i.e. `w1_to_w2[w1[i]]`) is not the same letter it corresponds to now (i.e. `w2[i]`), that would be one reason to return `false`, or...

```
w2_to_w1.count(w2[i]) && w2_to_w1[w2[i]] != w1[i]
```

...if we've already seen the same letter as `w2[i]` before in `w2` and the letter in `w1` it corresponded to before (i.e. `w2_to_w1[w2[i]]`) is not the same letter it corresponds to now (i.e. `w1[i]`), that would be another reason to return `false`.